# Grilling Large Shrimp To Even Doneness

Tags: grilling, shrimp

I have some large shrimp (maybe U6 or bigger) that I want to grill. I did this once and the main body came out perfectly cooked, but closer to the tail, they were overcooked. Naturally, this is due to the relative thickness of the meat.

What can I do to slow the cook near the tail while grilling?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the tail end of the shrimp in foil, possibly removing the foil for the last 30s of cooking.  This will allow the tail end to cook slower.